# Comparing Usernames on Android using an array

Tags: android

I'm making a simple form and I want to use an array stored in my strings.xml to compare with text entered by the user.

```
    Resources res = getResources();
    String[] usernameArray = res.getStringArray(R.array.usernames);
    int userint = usernameArray.length;
    for(int x=0;x<userint;x++){
        if(user.equals(usernameArray[x])){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Username already exists.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }
    }
```

-from strings.xml

```
<string-array name="usernames">
    <item>Bryan</item>
    <item>John</item>
    <item>Matt</item>
    <item>Mike</item>
</string-array>
```

When my app runs this part of my code, I get a lot of errors on logcat:

```
09-11 00:25:59.725: E/AndroidRuntime(810): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-11 00:25:59.725: E/AndroidRuntime(810): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
09-11 00:25:59.725: E/AndroidRuntime(810):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3633)
09-11 00:25:59.725: E/AndroidRuntime(810):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)
09-11 00:25:59.725: E/AndroidRuntime(810):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721)
09-11 00:25:59.725: E/AndroidRuntime(810):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
09-11 00:25:59.725: E/AndroidRuntime(810):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-11 00:25:59.725: E/AndroidRuntime(810):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-11 00:25:59.725: E/AndroidRuntime(810):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
09-11 00:25:59.725: E/AndroidRuntime(810):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-11 00:25:59.725: E/AndroidRuntime(810):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
09-11 00:25:59.725: E/AndroidRuntime(810):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
09-11 00:25:59.725: E/AndroidRuntime(810):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
09-11 00:25:59.725: E/AndroidRuntime(810):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-11 00:25:59.725: E/AndroidRuntime(810): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
09-11 00:25:59.725: E/AndroidRuntime(810):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-11 00:25:59.725: E/AndroidRuntime(810):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
09-11 00:25:59.725: E/AndroidRuntime(810):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3628)
09-11 00:25:59.725: E/AndroidRuntime(810):  ... 11 more
09-11 00:25:59.725: E/AndroidRuntime(810): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.Button cannot be cast to android.widget.RadioButton
09-11 00:25:59.725: E/AndroidRuntime(810):  at com.example.myapplication.MainActivity.hitClear(MainActivity.java:81)
09-11 00:25:59.725: E/AndroidRuntime(810):  ... 14 more
```

Also: I was asked when asking another question to post where LogCat said which line my error occurred, although mine does not. Is there a way to enable that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.Button cannot be cast to android.widget.RadioButton
```

See here. Error not from String resource. Check your xml. You are trying to convert `Button` to `RadioButton`. Please correct it.

Answer (score 1):

This is your real problem:

> android.widget.Button cannot be cast to android.widget.RadioButton

Answer (score 1):

```
09-11 00:25:59.725: E/AndroidRuntime(810): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.Button cannot be cast to android.widget.RadioButton
09-11 00:25:59.725: E/AndroidRuntime(810):  at com.example.myapplication.MainActivity.hitClear(MainActivity.java:81)
```

Check MainActivity.java, line 81. You likely have something like:

```
RadioButton button = (RadioButton) findById( R.id... );
```

Where the `R.id...` refers to a `Button`, not a `RadioButton`.